# Method that can keep track of where i am in the string, blanks, and stop the loop

Tags: java

```
@Test
public void testBlankPosition()
{
    assertEquals(10, sc1.blankPosition(3));
    assertEquals(24, sc2.blankPosition(4));
}
```

---

So this gives me 11 instead of the expected 10. I'm not sure whats going wrong with it.It's supposed to return the index of the blank that blankNum is asking for.

```
public Object blankPosition(int blankNum)
{
int blank = 0;
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
while ( i < sentence.length() && blankNum > blank)
{
    if (sentence.charAt(i) != ' ')
    {
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
            count++;
            i++;
            blank++;

        }
    }
}
{
    return count;
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should enhance your code like this:

```
        public Object blankPosition(int blankNum) {
            int blank = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < sentence.length()) {
                if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    blank++;
                    if (blank == blankNum)
                        return i;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return i;
        }
```

It maybe give the correct result as you expected

Comment: This works but the loop doesn't stop, would I put a break statement to stop that?

Comment: I already test the code and it is ok. If you return i; in the if statement, it means that you stop running the method and return the value for caller method

Comment: Okay alright yes my apologies, thank you very much I was over complicating what i had to do